# Error: could not find function install.packages

Tags: r, powerbi, install.packages

Whenever I try to create R visual objects on Power BI using packages that were previously installed through RStudio I always get the error specified on the Title of this post. I just can't seem to understand why, since this function works properly on RStudio and, furthermore, it's not event present in my code since, like I said, the packages I need are already installed.

I've double checked and the library directory/path is the same on both RStudio and Power BI, so I'm running out of ideas as to why this happens. R version is 4.2.2.

Comment: RStudio does not have a version 4.2.2, that's your version of R. They are not the same thing at all.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue: I had an .Rprofile file opened with install.packages in it; once deleted, I could run the code with no problem.